# Can I create an xml that specifies element from 2 nested xsd's without using a prefixes?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, xml-validation

I have 2 xsd's which are nested:

**DefaultSchema.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="DefaultSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name="ZForm">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Part" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Part"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Title" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Part">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Label" type="Label" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Title" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Label">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**ExportSchema.xsd:** (this one kinda wraps 1 more element (ZForms) around the main element (ZForm) of the DefaultSchema)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ExportSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://myNamespace.com/ExportSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:es="http://myNamespace.com/ExportSchema.xsd"
>
  <xs:import namespace="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd" schemaLocation="DefaultSchema.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="ZForms" type="es:ZFormType"></xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="ZFormType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ZForm" type="ZForm" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And then finally I have a **generated xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ZForms xmlns="http://myNamespace.com/ExportSchema.xsd">
  <ZForm Version="1" Title="FormTitle">
    <Part Title="PartTitle" >
      <Label Title="LabelTitle" />
    </Part>
  </ZForm>
</ZForms>
```

Visual studio complains it doesn't know what 'Part' is.
I was hoping I do not need to use xml namespace prefixes (..) to make this xml validate, since ExportSchema.xsd has a reference to the DefaultSChema.xsd.

Is there any way to make that xml structure valid without explicitly specifying the DefaultSchema.xsd? Or is this a no go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work (without namespace prefixes) if you change from `import` to `include` your base schema:

**ExportSchema.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ExportSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="DefaultSchema.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="ZForms" type="ZFormType"></xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ZFormType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ZForm" type="ZForm" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note: This will also require to change your target namespace to your DefaultSchema.xsd.

[From MSDN on xsd:import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256480):

> The difference between the **include** element and the **import** element is that import element allows references to schema components from schema documents with different target namespaces and the include element adds the schema components from other schema documents that have the same target namespace (or no specified target namespace) to the containing schema. In short, the import element allows you to use schema components from any schema; the include element allows you to add all the components of an included schema to the containing schema.

**DefaultSchema.xsd** (no changes with your version)

**Test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ZForms 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd ExportSchema.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd">
  <ZForm Version="1" Title="FormTitle">    
    <Part Title="PartTitle" >      
      <Label Title="LabelTitle" />      
    </Part>
  </ZForm>
</ZForms>
```

This combination seems to work..

Comment: This looks like being a step in the good direction. Any idea why VS is now not showing intellisense? Also, I downloaded xmlspy (30 day trial) and tried validating the xml against the (nested) ExportSchma.xsd. It keeps complainging about: "unable to locate a reference to a supported schema type (DTD, W3C Schema) within this document instance" and for now, I didn't find a way around this.
Were you able to validate the xml?

Comment: ok, I found the correct 'combination' :)
I will update your answer and mark is as correct, since you pointed me to the core of the problem. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your schema document DefaultSchema has targetNamespace="http://myNamespace.com/DefaultSchema.xsd" so it is saying that the ZForm, Part, and Label elements must be in this namespace. But in your instance, these elements are not in this namespace. Your instance is therefore not valid against this schema.